# Issue Related to SUM function in SSRS Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have webapplication having SSRS Reports inside..

In My .rdlc Report i have to make total of Positive values in the footer row..

so i have written following syntax in the column expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(CDec(Fields!Total.Value)>0,CDec(Fields!Total.Value),0))
```

when i run report.. it shows `#Error` in the column value.....

however, if i write it to convert `Fields!Total.Value` fields into int as follows, it works Correctly :

```
=SUM(IIF(Cint(Fields!Total.Value)>0,Cint(Fields!Total.Value),0))
```

what is the problem in first expression.. as i convert it into decimal it throws an error.
what is the solution ??? ( `Fields!Total.Value` has decimal values)

Thanks

Comment: From what you described, try casting zero as well

Answer (score 0):

Odd problem, it might be because your text box property is set for int not dec so when it gets a dec it throws an error. to change this property. Whenever I have to format a value I don't use convert but simply change the case of the text box.
right click on the column => column properties => Number(tab) => number(select) (from there you can format it as you want)